# Call jQuery continuation exactly once instead of once for each element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Most jQuery methods have the form:

```
$elements.doSomething(continuation);
```

where `continuation` is a continuation which is executed *once per element* after `doSomething` has finished. For example,

```
$("div.foo").fadeOut(function() { alert("One foo has been hidden."); });
```

will show "done" for *each* foo after it has been faded out.

Now I would like to execute the continuation *exactly once* after doSomething has been performed on *all* elements. If no elements are matched, the continuation should execute immediately. Example:

```
$("div.foo").fadeOut(... some magic here ... 
                     function() { alert("All foos have been hidden."); });
```

I could obviously implement this myself (by counting the invocations etc.), but I was wondering: Is there some jQuery built-in which already does this?

Answer (score 4):

Just found it myself by [RTFM-ing](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/):

> **As of jQuery 1.6**, the `.promise()` method can be used in conjunction with the `deferred.done()` method to execute a single callback for the animation as a whole when all matching elements have completed their animations.

Thus, the "magic" looks like this:

```
$("div.foo").fadeOut();
$("div.foo").promise().done(function() { alert("All foos have been hidden."); });
```

And a live working example:

```js
$("div.foo").fadeOut();
$("div.foo").promise().done(function() { alert("All foos have been hidden."); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">123</div>
<div class="foo">123</div>
<div class="foo">123</div>
```

Comment: Promise is the way to go!

Comment: Hit me by 20 seconds :) haha Got my +1

Comment: @Dekel: Sorry about that, I really appreciate you trying to help! :-)

Comment: Thats life :) you got my vote here for answering it yourself!

Comment: Hope you don't care - added a working example to your answer